# Deploying Storm build JAR

Tags: java, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

1. I developed a Java class which reads data from Kafka queue and prints it out

   ```
   ZkHosts zkHosts=new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
   String topic_name="test";
   String consumer_group_id="storm";
   String zookeeper_root="";
   SpoutConfig kafkaConfig=new SpoutConfig(zkHosts, 
           topic_name, zookeeper_root, consumer_group_id);
   kafkaConfig.scheme=new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
   /*kafkaConfig.forceFromStart=false;
   kafkaConfig.startOffsetTime =-2;*/

   KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(kafkaConfig);
   TopologyBuilder builder=new TopologyBuilder();
   //builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", kafkaSpout, 1);
   builder.setSpout("KafkaSpout", kafkaSpout);
   builder.setBolt("PrinterBolt", new PrinterBolt()).globalGrouping("KafkaSpout");
   Map<String, Object> conf = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   conf.put(Config.TRANSACTIONAL_ZOOKEEPER_PORT, 2181);
   conf.put(Config.TRANSACTIONAL_ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS, Arrays.asList("localhost"));
   conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_SESSION_TIMEOUT, 20000);
   conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 20000);
   conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_RETRY_TIMES, 3);
   conf.put(Config.STORM_ZOOKEEPER_RETRY_INTERVAL, 30);
   LocalCluster cluster=new LocalCluster();
   try{
       cluster.submitTopology("KafkaConsumerTopology", conf, builder.createTopology());
       Thread.sleep(120000);
   }catch (Exception e) {
       //throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't initialize the topology", e);
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
   ```
2. after coding, I am doing Maven build as JAR file and moved the jar to Amazon AWS cluster
3. and then running command like `nohup java -cp uber-***-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.***.&&&.kafka.App`

But I am facing an error here, could anyone tell me what mistake I am doing in deployment?. I am thinking following I have to do:

- I need to deploy this jar file in strom config folder, do I need to? but I did placed the jar in seperate folder in AWS (not in storm folder)
- how to see the sys outs
- do I need to include any yml files in my project?

Please find below exception:

```
29537 [Thread-14-KafkaSpout] ERROR backtype.storm.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.logger(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.logger$lzycompute(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.logger(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.debug(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.debug(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.connect(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.connect(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOrMakeConnection(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:77) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:67) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.<init>(PartitionManager.java:83) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:135) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3373$fn__3388$fn__3417.invoke(executor.clj:565) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__464.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting StackOverflowError. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop for more details.
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.<clinit>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:49) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The stack trace of the error would be helpful.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, i did added now at above. please check once.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, do you have any idea on this line, 
kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(Unknown Source) ~[uber-iot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, how to give the offsetBefore parameter to simple consumer?

Comment: I think kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore call  is  to get the offset header for a consumer group i.e. pointer from where consumer should start reading in a topic but this stack trace is not very useful. But i would suggest check zookeeper/kafka server is up/ test topic is created and has a leader etc.

Comment: In the past i got similar error when i halt the process in a debug point for a long time and topology fails with Aysnc Loop died. Why there is a thread.sleep ?

Comment: @vasa.v03, i checked zookeper and kafka server are in up and test topic is exist in kafka. And i too don't know why thread.sleep, i saw somewhere in browser for solution to above exception, so i did trail and error with it.

Comment: It seems you are providing two logging libraries: `log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar` -- Storm 0.9.x is using `log4j-over-slf4j.jar` -- try removing `slf4j-log4j12.jar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matthias J. Sax and everyone, thanks for your help.
The mistake i did here is, the deployment process i followed is wrong.
To deploy the toplogy build i have to folow below process,

1. Jar has to be push into storm AWS folder and then has to run below commands to         make it recognized by Storm

rm -f *.out

(nohup bin/storm nimbus > nimubus.out)&

(nohup bin/storm supervisor > supervisor.out)&

(nohup bin/storm jar topos/IoT.jar com.bridgera.iot.test.App01 > IoT.out)&

here i am telling the storm where it can find my jar and the main class from where it can find the topology builder...

Thanks guys...